# Change button color when pressed (multiple buttons)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio

Im doing a tictactoe game in vb.net and i would like to know how to change button color for example when setting X or O to a button, like when X is assigned turn the button blue and when O is assigned turn it green.

heres the code assign x or o

```
Private Sub AllButton_Click(sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If turn Mod 2 = 0 And sender.Content = "" Then
        sender.Content = "X"
    Else
        If sender.Content = "" Then
            sender.Content = "O"

        End If
    End If
    turn += 1
End Sub
```

Comment: If your buttons have a `Content` property, you might want to add the WPF tag and remove the VBA tag which cant be applicable

Comment: the turn variable is still being incremented, even if the content isn't equal to "".  This is going to cause logic problems if someone accidentally clicks on a button that's already been assigned.  This should likely only be incremented if a new value is assigned to the content.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it in code-behind, why not use XAML? Something like this:-

```
  <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Content" Value="X">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="Content" Value="O">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

Then assign it to your buttons:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" />
```

The style sets a default background of white, and uses triggers to change the background colour based on the button content ("X" or "O").

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it just be button1.BackColor

UPDATE: notice the 2 lines of code added to each section of the if statement

```
Private Sub AllButton_Click(sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If turn Mod 2 = 0 And sender.Content = "" Then
        sender.Content = "X"
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Blue
        Button2.BackColor = DefaultBackColor

Else
    If sender.Content = "" Then
        sender.Content = "O"
        Button2.BackColor = Color.Green
        Button1.BackColor = DefaultBackColor

    End If
End If
turn += 1
End Sub
```

Comment: setting button1 just assigns color to one button

Comment: so then why couldn't you have multiple lines of code? for example
button1.BackColor
button2.BackColor